# UV mapped texture being distorted by extruding and rotating

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, objects, image

I'm trying to make a castle tower with this rounded stick-out part on the side. I'm trying to add this brick texture image but it's warping at the part where I extruded and rotated.  I've tried Smart UV Unwrapping and other stuff but it never works properly. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: What I'm talking about]